# Unexpected token ) in line that does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'll rather post images than code itself to present the issue better, these are some of the last lines of my file:

[image]

It is clear that my code ends withing the 237th line. However when I type "npm start" from terminal I keep getting:

[image]
Looks like the syntax error is in nonexistent line of code.

I tripple checked the file, try introducing some syntax errors and checked if it catches them. I'm sure this the file npm tries to use. How come? Maybe this is something with sublime text? Has any of you ever experienced such a weird issue?

EDIT:

```
 var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'), //mongo connection
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'), //parses information from POST
    me

thodOverride = require('method-override'); //used to manipulate POST

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
router.use(methodOverride(function(req, res){
      if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
        // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
        var method = req.body._method
        delete req.body._method
        return method
      }
}))

//build the REST operations at the base for blobs
//this will be accessible from http://127.0.0.1:3000/blobs if the default route for / is left unchanged
router.route('/')
    //GET all blobs
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        //retrieve all blobs from Monogo
        mongoose.model('Blob').find({}, function (err, blobs) {
              if (err) {
                  return console.error(err);
              } else {
                  //respond to both HTML and JSON. JSON responses require 'Accept: application/json;' in the Request Header
                  res.format({
                      //HTML response will render the index.jade file in the views/blobs folder. We are also setting "blobs" to be an accessible variable in our jade view
                    html: function(){
                        res.render('blobs/index', {
                              title: 'All my Blobs',
                              "blobs" : blobs
                          });
                    },
                    //JSON response will show all blobs in JSON format
                    json: function(){
                        res.json(infophotos);
                    }
                });
              }     
        });
    })
    //POST a new blob
    .post(function(req, res) {
        // Get values from POST request. These can be done through forms or REST calls. These rely on the "name" attributes for forms
        var name = req.body.name;
        var badge = req.body.badge;
        var dob = req.body.dob;
        var company = req.body.company;
        var isloved = req.body.isloved;
        //call the create function for our database
        mongoose.model('Blob').create({
            name : name,
            badge : badge,
            dob : dob,
            isloved : isloved
        }, function (err, blob) {
              if (err) {
                  res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
              } else {
                  //Blob has been created
                  console.log('POST creating new blob: ' + blob);
                  res.format({
                      //HTML response will set the location and redirect back to the home page. You could also create a 'success' page if that's your thing
                    html: function(){
                        // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /adduser
                        res.location("blobs");
                        // And forward to success page
                        res.redirect("/blobs");
                    },
                    //JSON response will show the newly created blob
                    json: function(){
                        res.json(blob);
                    }
                });
              }
        })
    });



  /* GET New Blob page. */
router.get('/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('blobs/new', { title: 'Add New Blob' });
});



// route middleware to validate :id
router.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
    //console.log('validating ' + id + ' exists');
    //find the ID in the Database
    mongoose.model('Blob').findById(id, function (err, blob) {
        //if it isn't found, we are going to repond with 404
        if (err) {
            console.log(id + ' was not found');
            res.status(404)
            var err = new Error('Not Found');
            err.status = 404;
            res.format({
                html: function(){
                    next(err);
                 },
                json: function(){
                       res.json({message : err.status  + ' ' + err});
                 }
            });




            router.route('/:id')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    mongoose.model('Blob').findById(req.id, function (err, blob) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('GET Error: There was a problem retrieving: ' + err);
      } else {
        console.log('GET Retrieving ID: ' + blob._id);
        var blobdob = blob.dob.toISOString();
        blobdob = blobdob.substring(0, blobdob.indexOf('T'))
        res.format({
          html: function(){
              res.render('blobs/show', {
                "blobdob" : blobdob,
                "blob" : blob
              });
          },
          json: function(){
              res.json(blob);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  //GET the individual blob by Mongo ID
router.get('/:id/edit', function(req, res) {
    //search for the blob within Mongo
    mongoose.model('Blob').findById(req.id, function (err, blob) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('GET Error: There was a problem retrieving: ' + err);
        } else {
            //Return the blob
            console.log('GET Retrieving ID: ' + blob._id);
            //format the date properly for the value to show correctly in our edit form
          var blobdob = blob.dob.toISOString();
          blobdob = blobdob.substring(0, blobdob.indexOf('T'))
            res.format({
                //HTML response will render the 'edit.jade' template
                html: function(){
                       res.render('blobs/edit', {
                          title: 'Blob' + blob._id,
                        "blobdob" : blobdob,
                          "blob" : blob
                      });
                 },
                 //JSON response will return the JSON output
                json: function(){
                       res.json(blob);
                 }
            });
        }
    });
});


router.put('/:id/edit', function(req, res) {
    // Get our REST or form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var name = req.body.name;
    var badge = req.body.badge;
    var dob = req.body.dob;
    var company = req.body.company;
    var isloved = req.body.isloved;

   //find the document by ID
        mongoose.model('Blob').findById(req.id, function (err, blob) {
            //update it
            blob.update({
                name : name,
                badge : badge,
                dob : dob,
                isloved : isloved
            }, function (err, blobID) {
              if (err) {
                  res.send("There was a problem updating the information to the database: " + err);
              } 
              else {
                      //HTML responds by going back to the page or you can be fancy and create a new view that shows a success page.
                      res.format({
                          html: function(){
                               res.redirect("/blobs/" + blob._id);
                         },
                         //JSON responds showing the updated values
                        json: function(){
                               res.json(blob);
                         }
                      });
               }
            })
        });
});


//DELETE a Blob by ID
router.delete('/:id/edit', function (req, res){
    //find blob by ID
    mongoose.model('Blob').findById(req.id, function (err, blob) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } else {
            //remove it from Mongo
            blob.remove(function (err, blob) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
                } else {
                    //Returning success messages saying it was deleted
                    console.log('DELETE removing ID: ' + blob._id);
                    res.format({
                        //HTML returns us back to the main page, or you can create a success page
                          html: function(){
                               res.redirect("/blobs");
                         },
                         //JSON returns the item with the message that is has been deleted
                        json: function(){
                               res.json({message : 'deleted',
                                   item : blob
                               });
                         }
                      });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The code would be more useful than the image.

Comment: can you show that whole function, from the beginning?

Comment: well, instead of the image, can you pastebin the code? Seems you are not closing a bracket (parenthesis or curly braces)

Comment: I agree with Pointy, depperem and others. The full code is needed to solve this problem.

Comment: Sure guys, thanks. I just pasted it in

Comment: _"Unmatched '{'"_ at line 98.

Comment: @DCDC use something like [`jshint`](http://jshint.com/), which is what I'm using (in my editor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open:

```
// route middleware to validate :id
router.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
```

and don't close it.

Comment: Thanks! But why console replies with so misleading error about nonexistent line?

Comment: Because it's expecting a final closing bracket on the final closing line, i.e. `)};` and doesn't see it, so it 'adds' a line where it expects it.