# There Is no 344th Line

Tags: javascript

UPDATE: If anyone is looking here because they have a similar problem, look through your program for opening braces, but not closing them.

Weird, but simple little problem here:

My code has a total 343 lines of code, but when I try to run the program, it says there's an error at line **344**! There's not a 344th line! 
This error pops up:

```
:\Bot\index.js:344}); ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: Since we can’t see the file we can’t say anything about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your code would help.

Anyway, you probably opened curly braces and forgot to close them.

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406212/unexpected-token-in-line-that-does-not-exist).

Comment: My code is really long, that's why I didn't add it. (343 lines!) Thanks for the answer though.